# (Svelte 3) Can I put images close to the component that uses them?

Tags: javascript, svelte, svelte-3

I prefer to put images close to the component that uses them, instead of `public` folder. E.g., https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files/, the build process will copy the images to the `dist` folder. Is this supported in Svelte now?

Comment: If you configure your build tool (like webpack) to use a loader to handle images (like url-loader), it should work just like in a react app.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Jackyef, I have tested with rollup and [@rollup/plugin-image](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@rollup/plugin-image), it works.